# Performance decreases with a higher number of threads (no synchronization)

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance

I have a data structure (a vector) which elements have to be parsed by a function, where elements can be parsed by different threads.

Following is the parsing method:

```
void ConsumerPool::parse(size_t n_threads, size_t id)
{
    for (size_t idx = id; idx < nodes.size(); idx += n_threads)
    {
        // parse node
        //parse(nodes[idx]);
        parse(idx);
    }
}
```

Where:

- `n_threads` is the total number of threads
- `id` is the (univocal) index of the current thread

and the threads are created as follow:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;

for (size_t i = 0; i < n_threads; i++)
    threads.emplace_back(&ConsumerPool::parse, this, n_threads, i);
```

Unfortunately, even if this method works, the performance of my application decreases if the number of threads is *too high*. I would like to understand why the performance decreases even if there's no synchronization between these threads.

Following are the elapsed times (between the threads start and the last join() return) according to the number of threads used:

- 2 threads: 500 ms
- 3 threads: 385 ms
- 4 threads: 360 ms
- 5 threads: 475 ms
- 6 threads: 580 ms
- 7 threads: 635 ms
- 8 threads: 660 ms

The time necessary for the threads creation is always between 1/2 ms.
The software has been tested by using its release build. Following is my configuration:

```
2x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5507 @ 2.27GHz

Maximum speed:  2.26 GHz
Sockets:    2
Cores:  8
Logical processors: 8
Virtualization: Enabled
L1 cache:   512 KB
L2 cache:   2.0 MB
L3 cache:   8.0 MB
```

**EDIT:**

What the `parse()` function does is the following:

```
// data shared between threads (around 300k elements)
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> vfoo;
std::vector<rapidxml::xml_node<>*> nodes;
std::vector<std::string> layers;

void parse(int idx)
{
    auto p = vfoo[idx];

    // p->parse() allocate memory according to the content of the XML node
    if (!p->parse(nodes[idx], layers))
        vfoo[idx].reset();
}
```

Comment: Maybe the overhead in the creation of more threads becomes bigger than the complexity of the function `parse` itself

Comment: Even though you have 2 CPU's are you sure The OS sees/uses both of them?  It may also be a case of false sharing and when everything is running on one CPU that is minimized but once you switch to using both CPU's it starts to become more of an issue.

Comment: Does the function `parse` modify `nodes` or does it just read it?

Comment: @BiagioFesta "The time necessary for the threads creation is always between 1/2 ms" so that doesn't add up.

Comment: @NathanOliver I can clearly see from the Task Manager, as well as from the Resource Monitor, how my application exploits all the 8 cores available.

Comment: OK.  I would look into false sharing and cache misses then.

Comment: @AdrianJałoszewski it just reads.

Comment: Then it should be synchronization or the same resource's consumption inside parse(), maybe the function is memory bandwidth-critical.

Comment: What is the size of the vector being parsed ?

Comment: @shrike Almost 300k elements.

Comment: @Nick: could you add some more details about what function `parse()` does ?

Comment: @shrike Please see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update:

We still don't have a lot of info about the memory access patterns of `parse()`, and how much time it spends reading input data from memory vs. how much time spent writing/reading private scratch memory.

You say `p->parse()` "allocates memory according to the content of the XML node".  If it frees it again, you may see a big speedup from keeping a big-enough scratch buffer allocated in each thread.  Memory allocation/deallocation is a "global" thing that requires synchronization between threads.  A thread-aware allocator can hopefully handle an allocate/free / allocate/free pattern by satisfying allocations from memory just freed by *that* thread, so it's probably still hot in private L1 or L2 cache on that core.

**Use some kind of profiling to find the real hotspots**.  It might be memory allocation/deallocation, or it might be code that reads some memory.

---

Your dual-socket Nehalem Xeon doesn't have hyperthreading, so you can't be running into issues with threads slowing each other down if a non-HT-aware OS schedules two on two logical cores of the same physical core.

---

You should investigate with performance counters (e.g. Linux `perf stat`, or Intel's VTune) whether you're getting more cache misses per thread once you pass 4 threads.  Nehalem uses large shared (for the whole socket) L3 (aka last-level) caches, so more threads running on the same socket creates more pressure on that.  The relevant perf events will be something like LLC_something, IIRC.

**You should definitely look at L1/L2 misses**, and see how those scale with number of threads, and how that changes with strided vs. contiguous access to `node[]`.

There are other perf counters you can check to look for false sharing (one thread's private variable sharing a cache line with another thread's private variable, so the cache line bounces between cores).  Really just look for any perf events that change with number of threads; that could point the way towards an explanation.

---

A multi-socket system like your 2-socket Nehalem will have NUMA [(Non-uniform_memory_access)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access).  A NUMA-aware OS will try to allocate memory that's fast for the core doing the allocation.

So presumably your buffer has all of its physical pages in memory attached to one of your two sockets.  In this case it's probably not something you can or should avoid, since I assume you're filling the array in a single-threaded way before handing it off to multiple threads for parsing.  In general, though, try to allocate memory (especially scratch buffers) in the thread that will use it most, when that's convenient.

This may partially explain less-than-perfect scaling with number of threads.  Although more likely this has nothing to do with things, if @AntonMalyshev's answer didn't help.  Having each thread work on a contiguous range, instead of striding through the array with a stride of `n_threads`, should be better for L2 / L1 cache efficiency.

`node[]` is a vector of pointers (so with 8 threads, each thread uses only 8 bytes of each 64 byte cache line it touches in `node[]`).  However, each thread presumably touches way more memory in the pointed-to data structures and strings.  If `node` entries point to monotonically-increasing positions in other data structures and the string, then the strided access to `node[]` creates non-contiguous access patterns to most of the memory touched by the thread.

---

One possible benefit of the strided access pattern: **Strided means that if all threads run at more or less the same speed, they're all looking at the same part of memory at the same time.**  Threads that get ahead will slow down from L3 misses, while other threads catch up because they see L3 hits.  (Unless something happens that lets one thread get too far behind, like the OS de-scheduling it for a time slice.)

So maybe L3 vs. RAM bandwidth / latency is more of an issue than efficient use of per-core L2/L1.  Maybe with more threads, L3 bandwidth can't keep up with all the requests for the same cache lines from the L2 caches of multiple cores.  (L3 isn't fast enough to satisfy constant L2 misses from all cores at once, even if they all hit in L3.)

This argument applies to the everything pointed to by `node[]` only if contiguous ranges of `node[]` point to contiguous ranges of other memory.

Comment: @Nick: updated.  memory allocation/deallocation might be an issue.  You should definitely profile to see in more detail where the hotspots are.

Answer (score 7):

The processor you are using Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5507 has only 4 cores (see http://ark.intel.com/products/37100/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5507-4M-Cache-2_26-GHz-4_80-GTs-Intel-QPI).
So having more threads than 4 would cause the slow down because of the context switching as is visible from the data you have provided.

You can read more about the context switching at the following link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch

Comment: The configuration has 2 CPUs working in parallel. I tested my application and it uses all (8) cores.

Comment: In that case you might be hitting the memory wall, you should check what memory bandwidth is needed for each thread and if there is enaught memory bandwidth available. This might be the cause for the results you are having.

Comment: What does 'parse' actually do?  If you are constantly missing on the L3 cache performance can decrease as well.   Take a look at 'false sharing' and cache lines as a research topic

Comment: @MatthewFisher parse() essentially reads and parses a std::string (common to each thread) and allocate new data structures according to its content.

Comment: @Nick Do you mean that each thread is looking at the same std::string?  If so, try to make a copy and give it to each.  In general, read only access should be ok a box with a single memory (NUMA) bank but its worth a try.

Another possibility is L2/L3 misses due to the string being really big. In this case, try to chop the string into cache line size bit and see how it goes.

Also, see my answer about hyper-threading contention

Comment: @MatthewFisher Yes, the string is quite big (several MBs) and I can access this string only by using pointers to some of its locations. Could you elaborate when you say chop the string into cache line size bit? +1

Comment: @Nick Depending on the business problem, it may be possible to break your string into more manageable chunks. If so, having the different thread process those chunks in cache line size (64 bytes?) will be most cache efficient.  Lets imagine a case where thread 1 processes bytes 0 to 1mb, thread 2 from 1mb to 2mb, etc.  Now each thread will work on a subsection of the string that is some multiple of the cache line size.  In this way, we can align the input date to be optimal to the cache structure.  The performance difference can be orders of magnitude.

Comment: @Nick: Edit this extra info into the question.  It's extremely low on details of what your code is doing and its memory access patterns.

Answer (score 3):

Try to parse continuos ranges of elements inside threads, e.g. change

```
for (size_t idx = id; idx < nodes.size(); idx += n_threads)
{
    // parse node
    parse(nodes[idx]);
}
```

to

```
for (size_t idx = id * nodes.size()/n_threads; idx < (id+1)*nodes.size()/n_threads; idx++)
{
    // parse node
    parse(nodes[idx]);
}
```

that should be better for caching.

Also it's better to precompute `size = (id+1)*nodes.size()/n_threads` and use it in loop's stop condition instead of computing it on each iteration.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't get very different results. It improves a bit when I use all cores but at the same time it gets worse when I use 4 threads.

Comment: Did you try to copy needed part of `nodes` into local array before processing? This should help to avoid memory and cache multicore access performance reduction.

Answer (score 2):

For CPU bound processes, adding additional threads beyond the number of available cores will decrease overall performance.  The decrease is due to scheduling and other kernel interactions.  For such situations, the optimal number of threads is often the number of cores -1.  The remaining core will be used by the kernel and other other running processes.

I address this topic in a bit more detail here [A case for minimal multithreading](http://matthewericfisher.tumblr.com/post/33854949531/a-case-for-minimal-multithreading)

Looking at the hardware and numbers a bit closer, I suspect you are hitting hyper-threading contention. For a 4 core cpu, 8 cores are simulated with hyper-threading. For a fully cpu bound process, hyper-threading will actually decrease performance.  There is some interesting discussion here [Hyper-threading](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/340555-28-intel-hyperthreading-helpful) and details [Wikipedia hyper-threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading)

Comment: That's not quite right.  Hyperthreading helps with *some* kinds of CPU-bound tasks, like ones that are limited by memory or instruction *latency*, branch mispredicts, or other things that don't saturate any of the shared resources of a core. (Shared things include L1/L2 cache capacity, or ALU execution resources like FP multiply throughput).  There would be no reason for hyperthreading to exist if it wasn't ever helpful to have two threads sharing the same core.  The first HT CPUs were P4, which had such limited execution resources that it was barely worth using.  Not so with Nehalem.

Comment: For example, HT helps significantly with video encoding (x264), which certainly does max out all hardware threads.

Comment: @PeterCordes interesting perspective! My work in this area has been concerned with latency rather than throughput.  Running a thread hot with cpu affinity and hyper-threading off was the best model for the lowest latency. I can how your example of video encoding would be more interested in throughput across all cores rather than latency on a single core.  Nick as you can see the topic is complex, certainly let us know how it turns out.

Comment: BTW, that model of Nehalem Xeon doesn't even have hyperthreading.  And yes, that makes sense that HT is worse for latency.  Many resources are statically partitioned when two HW threads are active on a core.  e.g. fetch/decode/issue bandwidth.  Others are competitively shared (like execution ports and cache).  See [Agner Fog's microarch pdf](http://agner.org/optimize/), and his Optimizing Assembly guide has some general advice / discussion about when HT is a win (e.g. branch-heavey code) and when it's break-even (e.g. code that already runs nearly 4 uops per clock) or a loss (e.g. cache size).

Comment: @PeterCordes Excellent point. Nick forget all that hyper-thread rubbish in that case.  Your box has two actual processors?  Seems like that is what your original post says now that I look at it closer (2x).  It is likely a L3 cache management issue in that case.  Make certain that you are not writing to a common area with multiple threads.  This will stale the cache and cause a fetch from main memory.   This is particularly bad on multi-cpu systems when one of the CPUs will be forced to read from the others memory bank.

Comment: I thought about NUMA issues while writing an answer, but the OP's comments on Anton's answer indicate that changing the strided access pattern to contiguous didn't help much / at all, which indicates that memory bandwidth to the `nodes` array isn't an issue.  Or actually, maybe having all threads working on the same part of it reduces the L3 footprint, by giving locality between threads in the shared L3 cache.  So maybe it's L3 size that's the issue, not the efficiency of L2/L1 usage.

Answer (score 2):

2 CPU (4 core each)
Threads run in a shared memory space. Performance decrease is caused by moving shared memory between CPU (threads cannot access directly cache in different CPU, more threads => more moving => bigger performance decrease).